# SharePoint 2010 - Creating a supplemental web.config file

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently developing a new feature for SharePoint 2010.  Along with the deployment of my feature I would like to add some settings to the `<appSettings/>` section within my SharePoint applications web.config.

I found some information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439965.aspx) regarding adding supplemental .config files during deployment, but I have not been able to get this to work.  This approach seemed the cleanest to me since I can have all my changes within a single file and have them deployed with the rest of my application.

I've created a `webconfig.MyApp.xml` file as suggested in the documentation, deployed it to the `<SharePoint 14 hive>\Config` folder, but my changes are not being propagated to my applications web.config.

Below is a sample snippet from my supplemental config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<actions>
    <add path="configuration/appSettings">
        <add key="MyFeatureKey" value="MyFeatureValue" />
    </add>
</actions>
```

I would like to avoid having to manually edit the web.config since those changes can easily be lost during SharePoint maintenance, etc.

If you have any ideas on an alternate maintainable approach to deploying web.config changes, my ears are open.

**UPDATE:**
The answers that have been given so far are great and I'm sure they will work.  But I'm looking for a solution that can be packaged up within my single `WSP` and deployed without any additional steps required.

Comment: Regarding your supplemental file not being applied to web.config:

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439965.aspx):

"You can retroactively apply changes to the web.config files of the server by running the copyappbincontent Stsadm command-line operation. You must run the operation on each front-end web server in the deployment."

Comment: @Jason Weber - That was it, running `stsadm -o copyappbincontent` was the missing piece... I guess i glazed over that line in the docs.  If you want to add that as an answer I will give you credit for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your supplemental file not being applied to web.config: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439965.aspx): "You can retroactively apply changes to the web.config files of the server by running the copyappbincontent Stsadm command-line operation. You must run the operation on each front-end web server in the deployment."

Comment: Note that this operation will deploy config changes to all of the web applications on the machine.

Answer (score 5):

As Russ and breischl suggest, you can make use of the WebConfigModifications property of the SPWebApplication object. To deploy this together with your feature, put your code in a feature receiver. That way, you can make the web.config modifications automatically when the feature is installed.

In your feature receiver, don't forget to call the ApplyWebConfigModifications() property on your SPWebApplication object.

Example:
http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/01/21/web.config-modifications-with-a-sharepoint-feature.aspx

You can package both your feature and your feature receiver assembly in a single wsp package.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'm getting an error when attempting this approach.  I've added a seperate SO question to track this error @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478441/sharepoint-2010-receiving-error-attempting-to-use-spwebconfigmodification

Comment: This approach seems to address all of the Wallace's concerns.  This may not work if the order of entries under a node matters e.g. for HttpModule registration.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a supplemental config file, the web.config modifications are **NOT automatically merged** until you make a call to `stsadm -o copyappbincontent`.

You can also force this command to be run through a `FeatureReceiver`.

After exploring the `stsadm` tool in reflector I found that the `copyappbincontent` operation makes a call to `SPWebApplication.WebService.ApplyApplicationContentToLocalServer()`'

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    var webApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
    webApp.WebService.ApplyApplicationContentToLocalServer();
}
```

Props to **@Jason Weber** for figuring this out, but unfortunately he put his answer in a comment rather than a question.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a file called AddWebConfigMods.ps1

```
Param ($weburl, $WebConfigModifications )

$url = New-Object System.Uri($webUrl)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") | Out-Null
$webApp = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($url)


#delete mods by the owners being added
$ownerstodelete = $WebConfigModifications | Group-Object owner | Select-Object Name

foreach($owner in $ownerstodelete)
{
    $modstodelete = @()
    foreach($mod in $webApp.WebConfigModifications)
    {
        if($mod.Owner -eq $owner.Name)
        {
            $modstodelete += $mod
        }
    }

    Write-Host ("Deleting " + $modstodelete.Count + " mods for owner: " + $owner)

    foreach($delmod in $modstodelete)
    {
        Write-Host (" + Deleting " + $delmod.Value)
        $webApp.WebConfigModifications.Remove($delmod) | Out-Null
    }
}

#this is where we start to add mods
$i = 0;

Write-Host ("Adding " + $WebConfigModifications.Count + " webconfig modifications to " + $weburl) 

foreach($modEntry in $WebConfigModifications)
{
    Write-Host (" + Adding " + $modEntry.Value)

    $mod = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
    $mod.Path = $modEntry.Path
    $mod.Name = $modEntry.Name
    $mod.Sequence = $i++
    $mod.Owner = $modEntry.Owner
    $mod.Type = $modEntry.Type
    $mod.Value = $modEntry.Value

    $webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add($mod)

}

$webApp.Update()
$webApp.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
```

Then create a csv file with your configs like so

```
Name,Path,Owner,Type,Value
system.serviceModel,configuration,alinean-common,EnsureSection,<system.serviceModel/>
connectionStrings,configuration,alinean-common,EnsureSection,<connectionStrings />
appSettings,configuration,alinean-common,EnsureSection,<appSettings />
serviceHostingEnvironment,configuration/system.serviceModel,alinean-common,EnsureChildNode,<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled='true'/>
```

Then in another ps1 script, ideally the one you use to deploy your solution, import the csv config options and call the function created in the first code block:

```
#read config mods from CSVs
$mods = Import-CSV .\config\admin-common.webconfigmods.csv

Write-Host "Applying configuration modifications"
#add web config mods to sharepoint using powershell script
&.\AddWebConfigMods "[sharepoint site url]" $mods
&stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```

Comment: This all looks great and I'm sure it will work.  But it's still an additional step.  Ideally I'd like everything to be bundled within my 1 wsp package for easy client deployment.

Comment: If it helps, you only need to run the script once. Afterwhich each time you upgrade the wsp, SharePoint apply's the web config modifications for you.

I hear what your saying though and hopefully someone else can chime in with a better solution.